# is p-value deprecated in h2o glm

Tags: r, h2o

Is p-value deprecated in elasticnet? Below reference shows the p-value in coefficients
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html

But I don't see p-values when I execute below command

```
 head(elastic_net_best_model@model$coefficients_table)
 Coefficients: glm coefficients

              names  coefficients standardized_coefficients
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

p values will only be computed if compute_p_values is set to true, and this will also only work if there is no regularisation, which requires lambda=0

As an example,

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
x<-as.h2o(iris)
xg<-h2o.glm(y="Sepal.Length",training_frame=x,compute_p_values=TRUE,lambda=0)
head(xg@model$coefficients_table)
```

This gives as output:

```
Coefficients: glm coefficients
               names coefficients std_error   z_value  p_value standardized_coefficients
1          Intercept     2.171266  0.279794  7.760227 0.000000                  6.425687
2 Species.versicolor    -0.723562  0.240169 -3.012721 0.003060                 -0.723562
3  Species.virginica    -1.023498  0.333726 -3.066878 0.002584                 -1.023498
4        Sepal.Width     0.495889  0.086070  5.761466 0.000000                  0.216141
5       Petal.Length     0.829244  0.068528 12.100867 0.000000                  1.463863
6        Petal.Width    -0.315155  0.151196 -2.084418 0.038888                 -0.240223
```